# Adding entries to a table using an exclusion list

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I have two tables:

Parts
   part_no nchar(15)

Models_Parts
   model_no nchar(10)
   part_no  nchar(15)

Models_Parts has 35,000+ entries. Parts has 1800 entries with no corresponding entry in Models_Parts. I need to create those entries with the model_no 'NO MODEL'. I am currently identifying those 1800 entries with:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT  p.part_no
  FROM  dbo.parts   AS  p
  WHERE p.part_no NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  mp.part_no
    FROM    models_parts        AS  mp
    )
```

Is there a quick and easy way to make those entries? Performance is no an issue.

Comment: If performance is not an issue, then there isn't really anything wrong with your query (apart that you haven't added `'NO MODEL'`)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following:

```
insert into Models_Parts (model_no, part_no)
select 'NO MODEL', part_no
from Parts
where not exists
(
select 1
from Models_Parts
where part_no = Parts.part_no
)
group by part_no
```

Comment: @DominicRomano if this solution solved your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted". Also please consider reviewing your other questions, and accepting any relevant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    insert into Models_Parts (model_no, part_no)
    SELECT    DISTINCT  'NO MODEL', p.part_no
  FROM  dbo.parts   AS  p
  WHERE p.part_no NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  mp.part_no
    FROM    models_parts        AS  mp
    )
```